# Automatically add analyzer to property when indexing

Tags: elasticsearch

So I followed [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html) tutorial on how to set up Partial Word Searching using ngrams for compound words. In the mapping when creating the index they specify:

```
"mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "text": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "trigrams" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So how would I allow elasticsearch to add that `"analyzer": "trigram"` property to a new field when I index a document. Lets say I have a new property called `homeNumber` how would I set it too.

```
"homeNumber": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "trigrams" 
 }
```

Comment: I hope my answer, give me any questions you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Mapping API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html), eg. in the first sense example under "mapping" on the [page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html) you linked.

Comment: Is there a way that the index mapping is updated with the `homeNumber` fields with out `PUT`ing a new mapping?

Comment: [Dynamic mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-mapping) will create the mapping for homeNumber if it hasn't been specified. But it will not dynamically place the analyzer "trigrams" in the mapping.